# Specifying a nested context path in Tomcat using autodeploy inside webapps/

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, tomcat8, contextpath

I know that in a default Tomcat 8 configuration I can drop a file `foo.war` file into the `webapps/` directory, and Tomcat will autodeploy my web app with a context path of `/foo/`.

Bu what WAR filename would I use if I wanted the context path to be `/foo/bar`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deploying a WAR file named `foo#bar.war` into `webapps` would result in a context path of `/foo/bar`. See [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference: The Context Container: Naming](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Naming).